# Got import error when using swiper 10.3 in angular 15 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import, swiper.js

When I use swiper library (https://swiperjs.com/get-started)  in an angular project to implement carousal, I got a compile error which complains the following:

```
**Error: node_modules/swiper/types/modules/index.d.ts:1:35 - error TS2691: An import path cannot end with a '.d.ts' extension. Consider importing '../shared.js' instead.

1 import type { SwiperModule } from '../shared.d.ts';**
```

This is almost the latest version of swiper. Based on what I read online, it is not supposed to import from *.d.ts file, instead, it should be just the name without d.ts.  In this case, what should I do?  But it seems this library is widely used and it shouldn't have such obvious issues...

I have tried to change the import line from shared.d.ts to shared, it works. But this is a library and I don't want to modify it.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the very same issue